# How to format cowsay output from a bash script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, format

I have a custom motd within a bash script that prints cowsay through this command,

```
/usr/games/fortune | cowsay -f www
```

I want to find out if there is a way of formatting this output such as shifting the output by a tab or a space ? Do I have to loop through the text manually formatting each line or is there a shorter/better way ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sed` to prepend the output with some other text. The following command adds a tab at the beginning of each line:

```
/usr/games/fortune | cowsay -f www | sed -e 's/^/\t/'
```

Comment: I want to be able to do this within a bash script. So for example within /etc/update-motd.d/00-header

Comment: @kuzyt: You are using the program `sed` from the `bash` script, the same way you are using `fortune` and `cowsay`. Of course, you can also write a loop with the bash builtins, but it requires more code.

Comment: @nosid I was trying make it so it would grab a random cow file, this is what I did:

fortune | cowsay -f `shuf -n1 -e path/to/my/cows/*`  | sed -e 's/^/\    /'

the `shuf` command does return a random file inside that folder when I run it alone, however when I nested it like I put above, I keep getting the same cow file. Can you shed some light on how to make it happen? Thanks!